# Navigation bar hover effects + image with sub nav

Tags: jquery, css, html

I need to create a responsive nav bar, that changes the images of subcategories on  hover. (subcategories loaded with images)

Comment: Do you have some issue you want help with? Please let us know what you've tried and what issue your facing. In it's current state, this is way too broad and unspecific. SO isn't a free coding service. You're expected to write the code yourself and if you run into some specific issue with your existing code, we can help with that.

Comment: Please read the Stack Overflow Code of Conduct before posting. https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: I need a full code nav bar creation

Comment: That's not how this site works. Please see my first comment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-) Before asking a question here, the community expects you to make a research on your own first and try to solve the problem yourself. Only if you can not do it alone, you should ask a question and add the code you already produced, as well as specifying the specific problem you encounter. Therefore you should give that a try and edit your question to add the code you created and specify the problem which you can not solve yourself.

Comment: How to code my self if I don't know

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `:hover` selector and have its background change.

```
.your-div {
    background-image: url("orig.png");
}

.your-div:hover {
    // new image on hover
    background-image: url("on-hover.png");
}
```